# rotate pixel array in any given degree (e.g. 45 degree) in c++

Tags: c++, rotation

I am Trying to rotate an RGB/RGBA image in 45 degree in c++.
I have the pixels of the image stored in unsigned char *pBuffer.
I have found this code for 90 degree rotation -

```
void rotate90(unsigned char *buffer, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height)
{
    const unsigned int sizeBuffer = width * height * 3; 
    unsigned char *tempBuffer = new unsigned char[sizeBuffer];

    for (int y = 0, destinationColumn = height - 1; y < height; ++y, --destinationColumn)
    {
        int offset = y * width;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            tempBuffer[(x * height) + destinationColumn] = buffer[offset + x];
        }
    }

    // Copy rotated pixels

    memcpy(buffer, tempBuffer, sizeBuffer);
    delete[] tempBuffer;
}
```

But i want to rotate my image in any given degree for rotation in C++

Comment: Multiplication of two complex numbers adds the angles and multiplies the vector lengths (distance from origin). Thus if you consider a point (x, y) as a complex number, and multiply by a complex number of length 1 and angle V, then you'll rotate by V. A vector of length 1 at 45 degrees would go to (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)). As you can see from the presence of an irrational number, you don't get completely overlapping pixels. So to get a nice result you would ideally sample pixels in the neighborhood and do some weighted average. Another idea is to enlarge the image, rotate, and scale down again.

Comment: But instead of doing that explicitly with DIY code, why not just use some image processing library that does it for you? OpenCV comes to mind, as well as the Boost sublibrary for image handling (based on Intel's, IIRC). Here's an [example of affine transformation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/gil/example/affine.cpp) using Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. You need to implement some kind of interpolation.

Long answer. First of all keep in mind that resulting bitmap will have a different size. For example if you have a 100x100 pixel image the 45 degrees rotated image will have size of 141x141 pixels, but only the central part will have original pixels, the cornerswill be empty (white? transparent? is up to you).

Regarding how to compute the central pixels I suggest you to do as follows: for each pixel in the destination picture implements the rotation that maps it back in the original one. This implies floating point computations and you will end with a result like 32.4;12.7 Now you have a few choices. The simplest is just round the result to the closest integer approximation and get that pixel. This will give a grained result but may be acceptable in come cases. Or you can get the 4 closest pixel and interpolate them. Linear interpolation is an option but gives a somewhat blurry result, other schemes are possible (cubic)